# Facing "object required" issue while using UDF in xlwings in some excel files while at other files there is no issue at all

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I have created an UDF in python and trying to use it in excel. I am facing "object required" issue while using this UDF in xlwings in some excel files while at other excel files there is no issue at all.

I am taking all the measures as suggested in xlwings documentation such as:

1. xlwings add-in is installed successfully
2. Excel in which I am working is saved as XLSM (Macro Enabled Workbook) file
3. xlwings is referenced to a VBA Project (alt + F11--> Tools--> References )
4. Trust Center Logging enabled

What must be reason for this mysterious behavior?

Comment: I think you might be missing the reference to xlwings under VBA Editor > References ...

Comment: Thanks Felix. However I have referenced that in VBA editor. Please refer point no 3 above. Anything else I might be missing?